# WordPress gzinflate(): data error when debugging

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting the following warning when debugging my plugin with "Debug Bar" plugin.

```
WARNING: \wp-includes\class-http.php:1669 - gzinflate(): data error
```

I am using `wp_remote_post()` in the plugin & it is causing the error.

How can I fix that? Any clue ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Finally fixed it.Just set `$headers['Accept-Encoding']` to empty string: 

`wp_remote_post( $url,
array(
'headers' => array( 'Accept-Encoding' => '' ),
'sslverify' => false,
'timeout' => 300,
'body' => $params
)
);`

Comment: get a similar issue, not doing anything specific, pretty straight forward page template, includes 2 WP_Query loops - reseting post metadata after each - thats it. - any clue ? (note this also only appeared when I switched MAMP to PHP 5.4.1)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the argument [`'decompress' => false`](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API#Other_Arguments) and WordPress will set the correct header values for you. Like this:

```
wp_remote_post( 
    $url, 
    array( 'decompress' => false )
);
```